# WPF closing a dialog automatically after background worker is completed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I click the login button, my background worker starts processing and a loading dialog window shows up.

However, how can I close it after my task has been completed?

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AdjustControls(false);
    if (Username == null)
    {
        Error("Username required");
        return;
    }
    loading.ShowDialog();
    backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += login_backgroundWorker_DoWork;
    backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += login_backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += login_backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

}

private void login_backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    try
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
            loading.ShowDialog();
            Action closeAction = () => loading.Close();
            loading.Dispatcher.Invoke(closeAction);
            this.Close();
        }));
    }
    catch (Exception InputChangedException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(InputChangedException);
        if (InputChangedException != null)
        {
            Error(InputChangedException.Message);
        }
    }

}

private void login_backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void login_backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
    {
        loading.Close();
    }));
}
```

Comment: I doubt your background worker even runs until the dialog is closed

Comment: You are correct. I moved it to inside the dowork but it still cant close.

Comment: You do not need to use the Dispatcher in RunWorkerCompleted. That event is already fired in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it seems quite simple. I just needed to set an Action:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => loading.ShowDialog()));
```

This is to start it, then another time to close it